# How to set the virtual space color?

Tags: settings, pycharm

In the PyCharm CE 3.0 IDE I activated the option **PyCharm Preferences/Editor/Show virtual space at file bottom**.

Is it possible to set the virtual space to a different color than the normal background or to display an EOF indicator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this. However, you should not need a EOF or a different color because you cannot scroll down to more than a certain length *after* your last statement in a file.

Comment: yeah, that's true, you can't scroll beyond the final 2 lines of a file. in the meantime i figured out, that displaying line numbers helps :-). but i guess it would be nice if the tear lines on the left wouldn't continue beyond the file's actual length. anyway, i'm happy with displaying line numbers :-). thanks!